# AppScreener says that my SQL code has some SQL Injection vulnerabilities

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, sql-injection

I am developing a project where I will have a backup of some forums and information coming from Lotus Notes. I am using Flask to run the backend. After check my code with the code scanner AppScreener, it says that my SQL code has some SQL Injection vulnerabilities but I can't undestand why.

This is the AppScreener result:

```
for usuario in data:
print("Usuario", usuario)
status = usuario['estatus_usuario']
mail = usuario['email_usuario']
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute( "UPDATE administrador_usuarios SET estatus_usuario=%s
WHERE email=%s",(status,mail))  # ---> this is the line where according to AppScreener is the vulnerability present

conn.commit()
conn.close()
return json.dumps({"response":"ok"})
```

Could you tell me what I can do?

Comment: Don't build your queries using regular string interpolation. See [little johnny tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) for a humourous take on how this can be exploited. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061103/how-to-format-and-build-query-strings-in-python-sqlite) for a solution.

Comment: Or search for "SQL Injections" [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/sqlite3/), read the paragraph there and look at the example just above.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the DBAPI you're using for sql (pyodbc, pymysql, sqlite, etc). In most of these, I think the %s notation got depreciated a while ago. Best to use ? as people have commented (referenced links).

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention i am using PyMySQL as DB API